# Reduced adjective/adverb clause with past action/completed event

Tags: grammar, subordinate-clauses, writing, reduced-relative-clauses

**Original sentence**: 1) "Authorities are investigating whether a man who allegedly drove an SUV into a holiday parade in Waukesha, Wis., **killing** five people and **injuring** more than 40, was fleeing another crime scene."

**1_1**) "Authorities are investigating whether a man who allegedly drove an SUV into a holiday parade in Waukesha, Wis., **which killed** five people and **injured** more than 40, was fleeing another crime scene."

**1_2**) "Authorities are investigating whether a man who allegedly drove an SUV into a holiday parade in Waukesha, Wis. **before he killed** five people and **injured** more than 40, was fleeing another crime scene."

**Question**: Whether **1=1_1**, or **1=1_2**, or **both**?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the original sentence. I.2 is definitely wrong. It was driving the vehicle into the crowd that caused the deaths and injuries; the driver didn't get out and kill people in some other way.

Comment: Are the sentences, i.e., 1 and 1_1  interchangeable?

Comment: 1.1 is not a very good sentence. _Which_ has to refer to a noun previously mentioned. Obviously it was the man's action that caused the deaths, but grammatically speaking _which_ could refer to either the man, the SUV or the parade.

Comment: @KateBunting Not really. The 'which' can be used as non-identifying cluase and sitiational cluase, beside the identifying one. See the example and understand the use of 'which' in a sentence: "The station chief was fired, which means there is an open position. "

Comment: Granted, but I still don't consider 1.1 to be any improvement on the original.

Comment: @Airforce Only 1 is clear and ambiguous -- the gerund-participial "killing"clause indicates a resultant situation. 1.1 is possible, but on first reading it seems as though the antecedent of "which" is "an SUV", which makes little sense, when it actually refers to the VP "drove an SUV into a holiday parade in Waukesha, Wis.,".

Comment: @BillJ Normally, we can’t use -ing form for a single completed action, can we? So, your reply is suggesting that we can use a present participle (-ing) for an past action (e.g. killed), only if the clause implies a 'resultant situation'; did I understand you rightly? For example, we cannot construct the **1** like this: "Authorities are investigating whether a man allegedly **driving** an SUV into a holiday parade in Waukesha, Wis., killing five people and injuring more than 40, was fleeing another crime scene." ; can we?

Comment: Yes, we can. The _ing_ clause in 1. is an adjunct in clause structure, but such clauses don't have to imply a resultant situation, cf. "He came in [looking rather pleased with himself]" /  "Liz was lying by the pool [reading a novel]." Your last example is fine -- it is semantically similar to the relative construction "Authorities are investigating whether a man who was allegedly driving an SUV into a holiday parade in Waukesha, Wis., ..."

Comment: @BillJ We can only use an active participle phrase (-ing form) when we are describing a continuing action or situation (in past time, too), but We can’t use -ing form for a single completed action. Look at your own example in which you have used "who **was** allegedly **driving** an SUV..." instead of "who allegedly **drove** an SUV...".
Next in my little understanding, the example: "Liz was lying by the pool reading a novel" seems to be grammatically wrong since it needs conjuctions (e.g., while, as,) before the phrase 'reading'. Otherwise it would imply "the pool was reading a novel..."

Comment: @BillJ "He came in looking rather pleased with himself". The 'came in' is an intransitive verb and used as a phrasal verb. The object of this sentence is the enitre clause, i.e., looking rather pleased with himself.

Comment: There’s nothing ungrammatical about “Liz was lying by the pool reading a novel”. The participial clause “reading a novel” is clearly not intended to be a modifier in NP structure but a depictive adjunct in clause structure giving descriptive information about “Liz”.

Comment: Of course gerund-participial clauses can be used as adjuncts. You've got the grammar wrong: in my example "He came in [looking rather pleased with himself]", the verb is just "came" with "in" as complement. "Looking rather pleased with himself" is an adjunct. I don't know why you talk of 'object': there's no object in that example.

Comment: @BillJ Thanks for your time. Your construction is okay in spoken. English grammar rather advises to construct, “Reading a novel, Liz was lying by the pool.”, or "Liz, (who was) reading a novel, was lying by the pool."

Comment: Nonsense! The _Liz_ example I gave is clear and unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

1.1 is correct and has the same meaning as 1, though it has somewhat lower readability than 1 because on first read, "which" refers to the parade, and on only second read, refers to the man's action as a whole. Version 1 is unambiguous and reads cleanly the first time.

1.2 is incorrect because it means the driver first drove his car into the parade, then after that killed five people and injured 40 others, as if they were separate incidents, like, "The driver killed 5 people before fleeing the scene", which also describes two separate actions. It's clear from 1 that it was by driving his car into the parade that the driver killed and injured those people.

Comment: '1.1 has somewhat lower readability than 1.' -Is it because the usage of the 'which' in 1_2 might make the reader think about its connection to the event of ‘authority's investigation’, instead of ‘the man's driving an SUV into a holiday parade’?
Does it still look to have lower readability for this new example: **1_3)** "The man who allegedly drove an SUV into a holiday parade in Waukesha, Wis., which killed five people and injured more than 40, has been arrested."?

Comment: @Airforce I've added a bit to my answer about 1_1. Let me know if it helps. About 1_3, it has the same readability as 1_1. I don't think many people would read "which" to refer to "investigation" before the action of driving since it's so much farther away.

Comment: Of course it's helpful. Much appreciated. 'on first read, "which" refers to the parade'--Yes if there were no comma (,) before the 'which', or a 'that' were used, instead of the ',which' .

Comment: Normally, we can’t use -ing form for a single completed action, can we?  But in **1** the participle form (i.e. killing) is derived form a action verb (i.e. kill) and the action is in the past tense (which is understood by looking at the base verb, i.e., drove, of the clause).